# offset() returns different values for the same element in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

The page I'm building has two tabs (I'm uisng Bootstrap to create the tabs). The first (active/default) tab is long and makes the vertical scroll-bar appear. The second tab is short and the vertical scroll disappears when it becomes active.
The second tab contains just a text input and when focused, I report its position:

```
 var topleft = $("#input");
 console.log(topleft);
```

The strange thing is, on the same browser and the same loading of the page, the first time and second time I focus on the input I get different numbers for left:

> Object {top: 223, left: 358.5}
>
> Object {top: 223, left: 367}

The first number for left is as if there was a vertical scrollbar (although there is none), but the second one is correct. It seems like chrome cannot understand the change in scrollbar immediately.

Comment: can you make a fiddle or something.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is here, you may use the last one.

```
$(window).load(function () {
  var topleft = $("#input");
  console.log(topleft);
});

$(window).ready(function () {
  var topleft = $("#input");
  console.log(topleft);
});
```